# Applying the plugin 'kotlin-android' in an Instant App results in "null cannot be cast to non-null type com.android.build.gradleBasePlugin"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-instant-apps

I've been trying to combine the newly publicly released Android Instant Apps with the Kotlin programming language. After creating my project using the following (standard?) setup, I get an Error with the message **"null cannot be cast to non-null type com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin"** when I try to build the application. Using Kotlin works fine with standard **'com.android.application'** modules; the Error is thrown only when I try to use it within an Instant App module.

Top-level **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4"
    }
}

// ...
```

*app* module **build.gradle**, in which Kotlin **does** work:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // This will work.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

*base* module **build.gradle**, in which Kotlin **does not** work:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // This won't work.

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    feature project(':tracker')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // Kotlin standard library.
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${gradleKotlinVersion}"
}
```

*instantapp* module **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

*feature* module **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':base')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Again, the *app* module compiles without issues with this configuration; on the other hand, Android Studio / Gradle gives me this strange **"null cannot be cast to non-null type com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin"** error message, with the suggestions to re-download dependencies and sync the project (done) or restart Android Studio.

Are Instant Apps actually compatible with the Kotlin programming language ? I'm looking forward to your answers :)

PS: I use Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, with the latest updates installed from the Canary Channel for Build tools etc. My Kotlin plugin should be up-to-date as well.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much that this doesn't work right now. I can't even build a normal app (kotlin also) right now as transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug is constantly failing due to some exception in the com.android.build department. I fixed these issues by reverting to gradle plugin 2.3.2, but sadly this way you're losing advanced profiler support

Comment: Have you found workaround for the issue?

Comment: Absolutely not. I've subscribed to the issue on Google's Issue Tracker and I'm waiting for an update from their side on the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is addressed in [Kotlin plugin v1.1.2-5](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.1.2-5). Please update your version and try again.

For reference, the issue with previous plugin versions is being tracked here:

[38393607 | Issue building Instant apps with Kotlin enabled](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38393607)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38393607),This has been fixed.
In the meantime, you can manually update to the 1.1.3 kotlin plugin.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38393607) they will re-open to examine.